# Systrace: When I open the systrace, I found that the information of SurfaceFlinger is not full，I just see a few information shown

Tags: android, performance, systrace, ftrace

Android Version:10(Q)

The error systrace:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBxeW.png)

The normal systrace
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH8AN.png)

I have check the ftrace config in the code，the CONFIG_TRACING=y is already on my config

I can see ATRACE_CALL() on function SurfaceFlinger::onMessageReceived, but it's not shown on the systrace
And this is my command to capture the systrace:
python .\systrace.py gfx input view webview wm am sm audio video camera hal res dalvik rs bionic power pm ss database adb aidl sched irq i2c freq idle disk sync workq memreclaim regulators binder_driver binder_lock pagecache -o test7.html

I have tried to open these config,but it's not take effect

```
CONFIG_TRACER_MAX_TRACE=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_TRACER=y
CONFIG_FUNCATION_TRACER=y
CONFIG_PREEMPTIRQ_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_IRQSOFT_TRACER=y
CONFIG_TRACER_SNAPSHOT=y
CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE=y
CONFIG_FTRACE_MCOUNT_RECORD=y
```

Comment: I solved this problem by restart adb, input these command,"adb shell stop;adb shell start", but I still don't understand why this problem could be solved by this way

Answer (score 0):

`systrace.py` has been deprecated. Please consider [Android Studio CPU Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler)'s "System Trace" option or [Perfetto](https://perfetto.dev/). They have similar functionalities as `systrace.py`. Perfetto provides more data and it comes with a non-trivial learning curve.